# Lowercase specific character in a word using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a CMS and all blog titles are globally made uppercase, however I have several posts that contain the word "PDFs" and I would like to use jQuery or a similar solution to search in each blog title if it contains this word, and if it's there, I want to convert the last character from "PDFS" to lowercase.

This is what I've tried to do:

```
str = $('h1.class').text();
re = /\s(PDFS)\s/;
str = str.replace(re, 'PDFs');
```

The output is still not as expected.

Comment: [Please try to solve your problem yourself before seeking help](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: I've already tried but I couldn't achieve what I want.

Comment: Then please edit your question to include the code from your attempt, along with any error messages you may be getting, etc. See [ask]

Comment: try using regexp: /\s(PDFS)\s/ should find your PDFS with trailing whitespace characters. then substitute the "S"

Comment: I've tried, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this on jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".title_identifier").css("text-transform", "none").text(function () {
    return $(this).text().toUpperCase().replace("PDFS", "PDFs");
})
});
```

Test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/24bmqjLy/14/

Answer (score 0):

I prepare a sample code for answer. Please check it.

```js
var oldword=$("h1.class").html();
 
var newword=speacialWords(oldword);
$("h1.class").html(newword);

function speacialWords(word){
    
    var changed="none";
    var valArray = word.split(" ");
    var f = ['MYSQL','PDFS'];
    var r = ['M<span class="lowerCase ">y</span>SQL','PDF<span class="lowerCase ">s</span>'];
    var returnVal ="";
    for(x = 0; x < valArray.length; x++){
        for(y = 0; y < r.length; y ++){
            if (valArray[x].toLowerCase() == f[y].toLowerCase()){
                returnVal +="  "+r[y];
                changed="ok";
            } 
     
         }
         
         if(changed=="none"){ 
            returnVal +="  "+valArray[x];
             changed="none";
         }
    }
    returnVal = $.trim(returnVal);
    return returnVal 
    }
```

```css
.lowerCase { text-transform: lowercase;  }
p { text-transform: uppercase;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <h1 class="class">Hello Worlds PDFS</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, however I get an error in console:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined at speacialWords

Comment: Probably, It is caused by oldword value in your code. Please can you  check  oldword value in console.log ?

Comment: I'm not sure why but oldword's value is null, if I manually type the code for the oldword in console it gets it's value

Comment: can you try it now. i edit codes in snippet. But be sure the text you want to change must be  inside `<h1 class="class">THE TEXT YOU WANT TO CHANGE </h1>`

Comment: Ok, I've added this code under document.ready(), but now this is what I get when I type oldword in console: Uncaught ReferenceError: oldword is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: If the only change you've made is h1.class, I've already changed those.

Comment: yes it's. The problem you wrote is caused by `word` variable in speacialWords function. And the `word` comes from `var oldword=$("h1.class").html();`. So if you share the title code in your part,  i can help.